# How to get a class in a folder which can be implemented by an interface dynamically at .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

.NET CORE

I want to get class which has inherited by an interface like this :

Assume that these classes are in namespace of `For.Example.Classes`

```
FirmApiProcessor : IFirmApi

CompanyApiProcessor : ICompanyApi
```

x100 class more

I want to get class dynamically.

If i have an interface for example IFirmApi, i have to get FirmApiProcessor.

If i have ICompanyApi, i have to get CompanyApiProccessor.

I researched some sources but i cant do it. I guess that i have to use Assembly class and interface implementor or smth like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Then register each with the service collection at the composition root. `services.AddTransient<IFirmApi, FirmApiProcessor>(); services.AddTransient<ICompanyApi, CompanyApiProccessor>(); `

Comment: But i have a lot of classes. I dont want to map them. How to get them dynamically?

Comment: You are referring to auto registering them. Out of the box core DI does not do that but you can use a 3rp party container that does and can plug into core DI

Comment: i want use no DI. just creating class using method by using assembly class or smth. do you know about this ?